# Running GridsearchCV() in parallel

Tags: windows, python-3.x, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, grid-search

What are the computer hardware requirements to run a `GridsearchCV()` or `RandomizedsearchCV()` in parallel ( having either `n_jobs > 1` or `n_job == -1` )?

**Do all todays' computers support that?**

Answer (score 0):

**`Q`**: Do all todays' computers support that?
**`A`**: Yes, they certainly do.

The problem is with process-instantiation costs and with indirect-effects of the whole python-interpreter replica(s). For further details [ref. to **details explained** here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48637674).

Comment: Could you please explain How parallel related to that?

Comment: If you kindly re-read your bold question above, this text is answering exactly what you have asked there. Today's computers have both multi-core and/or many-core single-CPU / multi-CPU hardware resources well enough to allow for both "just"-[CONCURRENT] and to a certain level also [PARALLEL] process-scheduling on the hardware level, so there is nothing blocking you from using these hardware supported processing-capabilities, unless the actual code blocks or otherwise [SERIAL]-ises the flow of the processing blocks.

Comment: Thank you that means we sometime cannot get benefits from multi-core because of (Hardware limitations (memory) or software limitations (like in case of Windows OS) in these cases we have to run our code is serial ..Is my point correct?