# Running CrossValidationCV in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When I run a **`GridsearchCV()`** and a **`RandomizedsearchCV()`** methods in parallel ( having **`n_jobs>1`** or **`n_jobs=-1`** options set )
it shows this message:

> ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without
>   protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To
>   use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop
>   using "if name == 'main'". Please see the joblib documentation on
>   Parallel for more information" I put the code in a class in .py file
>   and call it using if_name_=='main in other .py file but it still shows
>   this message

It works good when **`n_jobs=1`**

```
import platform; print(platform.platform())
```

> ```
> Windows-10-10.0.10586-SP0
> ```

```
import numpy; print("NumPy", numpy.__version__)
```

> NumPy 1.13.1

```
import scipy; print("SciPy", scipy.__version__)
```

> SciPy 0.19.1

```
 import sklearn; print("Scikit-Learn", sklearn.__version__)
```

> Scikit-Learn 0.19.0

---

UPDATE

I tried this code but it still gives me the same error

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

class Test():
   def __init__(self):
          attributes = [..]
          dataset = pd.read_csv("..")
          X=dataset[[..]] 
          Y=dataset[...]
          model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
          model = RandomizedSearchCV(....)
          model.fit(X, Y)          
if __name__ == '__main__':
   Test()
```

Answer (score 0):

### **`joblib`** is know for this behaviour and rather explicit in documenting:

> **Warning**
>
> Under Windows, it is important to protect the main loop of code to avoid recursive spawning of `subprocesses` when using **`joblib.Parallel`**. In other words, you should be writing code like this:

```
import ....

def function1(...):
    ...

def function2(...):
    ...

...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # do stuff with imports and functions defined about
    ...
```

> No code should run outside of the **`“if __name__ == ‘__main__’”`** blocks, only imports and definitions.

So, refactor your code so as to meet this well-defined requirement and your code will start to benefit from the **`joblib`**-tools powers.

Comment: I tried this code (see the updated section)  but it still gives me the same error

Comment: The update does not cover the MCVE-formulation, you might review the post and decide to complete the MCVE to run it.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine this won't be the most useful answer, but you could always parallelize the process manually.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html